# Use Key Vault in Azure Arm Template

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template, azure-vm-templates

I'm creating a simple ARM template to create a VM.
For the "adminPassword" I'm using KeyVault (already configurated and with all the permissions in place).
Here there is the relevant part of the code:

```
      "adminPassword":{
      "reference":{
        "keyVault":{
           "id":"/subscriptions/d68628be-2a30-5d26-94c2-3d0145fb8e3e/resourceGroups/armtemplate/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/keyvaultfortemplate"
        },
        "secretName":"vmpassword"
     }

  }
```

Finally when I'm ready to start the deployment, I see it didn't get the "secret".

[Click here to see the empty password field on the portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiGWx.png)

Seems it couldn't retrive it from the KeyVault.
Any idea? Thanks

Comment: For the parameter value, reference the secret from the key vault. You reference the secret by passing the resource identifier of the key vault and the name of the secret. Refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/key-vault-parameter?tabs=azure-cli#reference-secrets-with-static-id).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass a sensitive value as a parameter, store the value in a key vault, and reference the key vault in your parameter file. **The sensitive value is securely retrieved during the deployment** that's why you are not able to see the value on the portal.

Deploy the template using Cloud Shell from the Azure portal or using the PowerShell that uses the Parameters file while deploying the template. You can use this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-tutorial-use-key-vault#deploy-the-template) to deploy the template that integrate Azure Key Vault.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Jagrati, so the only way is using PowerShell or Azure CLI? I really hope it was possibile to run the deployment without using other tools. Can you confirm that? Sorry but this is the first time I'm using Key Vault and I don't feel confident.

Comment: Follow the instructions given in the link, you can use Cloud Shell from the Azure Portal and easily deploy the template.